# Can a column be added to a record using XSD through SQLXMLBulkLoad?

Tags: sql, xml, xsd

I have a SQL Dts job pull an XML file and doing a SQLXMLBulkLoad using an XSD file.  Is there a way to specify in the XSD to append a static string column to every record of a certain table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Turn the XML file into a string, do a replace to add in the element i want, and turn it back into xml to send it to SQLXMLBulkLoad.  Quick and dirty.